# Centering an <img> in a <td>

Tags: css, html-table, centering

I'm trying to center an image within a table using CSS. Stackoverflow had others with the same problem and solved them using `margin:0 auto, text-align:center`, and/or `display:block`. None of these is forcing the `<img>` to be centered within my table cells.

http://fcilluminateconsulting.com/whats-my-card/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your img tag is getting float:left property coming from style.css

on line no. 16, add float:none property

```
table.cards td img {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: none; // give this property !
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove the `float` completely?

Comment: @ZombieCode yes it would be, but, i was expecting, Scott might have added it for some reason... its upto him..

Answer (score 1):

Your `img` tag is styled with `float:left`
change it.

```
media="all"
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

to

```
media="all"
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had set `text-align: right;` instead of `center` for this rule:

```
td.first-col, td.third-col, td.fifth-col, td.seventh-col {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Change it to this and it works fine:

```
td.first-col, td.third-col, td.fifth-col, td.seventh-col {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I apologize for the improper phrasing of the question. The problem I had was centering an image with the following code structure:<table><tr><td><img>

Comment: Changing the float to none (float:none) fixed my problem.